# How to translate a text which is in a StringFormat expression?

Tags: wpf

I'm using resources files for translation and a typical label is like below:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static Resx:FrmMngView.MsgLastModification}"/>
```

there are some cases that StringFormat is being used and I want to translate them:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.ItemCount, StringFormat=users: {0}}" />
```

which the translation of the word "user" in French is "utilisateur".
How can I use my resx translationkey here?

Answer (score 2):

You can just save the whole format string as resource and reference it in `Binding.StringFormat`.

Comment: i dont get the last part: Binding.StringFormat! could u tell me what chnages i should apply to the tag? <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.ItemCount, StringFormat=???}" />

Comment: @DanielBahmani: Just use `StringFormat={x:Static Resx:FrmMngView.UserLabelFormatString}` where that resource is the whole format string, i.e. `Users: {0}` and `Utilisateur: {0}` respectively.

Comment: it works. but how about image tags: <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Sys.Modules.Test;component/Resources/Serv-en.png"/>
instead Serv-fr.png?

Comment: @DanielBahmani: I would use another markup extension which returns the right image (already as `ImageSource`) from a key. (Also this has nothing to do with the original question, ask another one...)